# Is it correct to say "where don't you like to go? "

Tags: grammar, questions, negation

Is it correct to say "where don't you like to go?" or we must say "where do you not like to go?" . If both does it make any difference where to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are said and they are used differently.

"Where don't you like to go?" is often used to say that someone tends to like going to most places.

"Where do you not like to go?" is often used when asking where someone doesn't like to go, after finding out they do like going somewhere.

Comment: That depends on how much emphasis is put on "not"...  usually people say where do you NOT like to go, after finding out that person enjoyed visiting the slums in some country, a war zone, and a village ravaged by ebola...